# Assign variable length string to fixed length string

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to bridge some C code into Fortran. However, I'm having trouble getting the variable length C strings returned by the C API into the fixed length strings required by the Fortran API.

Here's a reduced version of the code that won't compile - I get `The shapes of the array expressions do not conform`.

```
character*200 function getValueFromC() 
  use cbridge
  implicit none

  type(c_ptr) :: resultString
  integer(kind=c_int) :: resultLength
  character, pointer, dimension(:) :: string

  call c_bridge_getValue(bridge, resultString, resultLength)
  call c_f_pointer(resultString, string, (/ resultLength /) )
  getValueFromC = string
  call c_bridge_releaseString(resultString)
end function getValueFromC
```

`cbridge` is just the module containing the `c_bridge_getValue()` and `c_bridge_releaseString` definitions, and the `bridge` pointer (just a `void*`)

`c_bridge_getValue()` just `malloc`s up a new string and returns it, and `c_bridge_releaseString()` `free`s the memory.

So my question is, what do I need to do to assign the `string` variable to the `getValueFromC`?

Comment: Always use tag fortran for Fortran questions. And your code is Fortran2003, so the fortran90 tag was inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to loop and assign to the string slices. I've not verified that this is 100% right, but it compiles for me...

```
character*200 function getValueFromC() 
  use cbridge
  implicit none

  type(c_ptr) :: resultString
  integer(kind=c_int) :: resultLength
  character, pointer, dimension(:) :: string

  call c_bridge_getValue(bridge, resultString, resultLength)
  call c_f_pointer(resultString, string, (/ resultLength /) )
  do i = 1, min(200, resultLength)
    getValueFromC(i:i) = string(i)
  end do
  call c_bridge_releaseString(resultString)
end function getValueFromC
```

Comment: That is correct, the problem is that `getValueFromC` is a character string (scalar) and `string` is an array of characters of length 1.

Comment: Yes, I'd say this is a valid solution, I am doing the same: https://bitbucket.org/apesteam/aotus/src/c2aafc4d76bafad7115867a6a0cd93406552a0a0/source/aot_top_module.f90?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#aot_top_module.f90-282